# Ask for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission from two different functions in the same activity

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

I have two different functions for takeScreenshot and saveAsPDF, both of them requires WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. But how can I create a switch case in `onRequestPermissionsResult` for same permission in the same Activity because `requestCode` is same in both the cases.

Comment: in your case you just have to check if ExternalWritePermission is granted or not, for that just check permission if it's granted or not via function that i have shown in PermissionCheck class in my answer,and if it's not granted then askPermission and it's only needed once for both taking ScreenShot and saveAsPdf, you just have to check it's granted or not.

Answer (score 1):

you can create separate class like following to check and ask permission ->

```
public class PermissionCheck {

    private static final String TAG = PermissionCheck.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context context;
    private static final int EXTERNAL_WRITE_PERMISSION_CODE = 620;
    private static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE = 335;

    public PermissionCheck(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    //  Check Required Permissions...
    public boolean CheckRequestedPermission(Context context, String CheckRequiredPermission) {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, CheckRequiredPermission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    //  To Request Permission...
    private void requestPermission(final Context context, final String RequestedPermission, final int PermissionCode) {
        if (!CheckRequestedPermission(context, RequestedPermission)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{RequestedPermission}, PermissionCode);
        }
    }


    //  Just add Permission Code that you required to get permissions and call this method...
    public void AskPermission(int RequestCode) {
        switch (RequestCode) {
            case EXTERNAL_WRITE_PERMISSION_CODE:
                requestPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, EXTERNAL_WRITE_PERMISSION_CODE);
                break;
            case CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE:
                requestPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA, CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and ask whatever permission you want and implement OnRequestPermissionResult in Activity or fragment like following.

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case EXTERNAL_WRITE_PERMISSION_CODE:
                Log.d(TAG, "onPermissionResult : Permission Granted? " + IsExternalWritePermissionGranted);
                //  changing value based on permission Deny/Accept
                IsExternalWritePermissionGranted = permissionCheck.CheckRequestedPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                break;
            case CAMERA_PERMISSION:
                //  changing value based on permission Deny/Accept
                IsCameraPermissionGranted = permissionCheck.CheckRequestedPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
                break;
        }
    }
```

**Note that the permission code you pass from activity/fragment to PermissionCheck should be same, as in the PermissionCheck class.**